# Joomla 3: Hide Class on Home Page

Tags: php, html, css, joomla, content-management-system

I would like to hide a class only on the home page.

```
<div class="search-wrapper">

.search-wrapper {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3d4895;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

So this must display on all pages. Except home page. I just cant get this right.

I have created the HOME PAGE menu item to have a page class, but still cant target .seacrh-wrapper on home page only.

Comment: is the seacrh-wrapper is inside item class ?

Comment: Can't you just wrap that version of the div in the condition of being on the default page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible, make the section you are wanting to hide a module, and set up the appropriate module area in your template. That way, you can assign it to all pages but the homepage.  This method has the benefit that the page isn't churning out unnecessary hidden content.

Failing that, add the following to your template:

```
<?php
$pageclass="";
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
       $pageclass="homepage";
}
?>
```

And then, in your body tag...

```
<body class="<?php echo $pageclass; ?>">
```

This will add a class of "homepage" to the body tag on the homepage.  Styles can then be added to the homepage only like this...

```
.homepage .search-wrapper {
    display:none;
}
```

No need for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jquery, use the following line:

```
//Here you check if the user is on the homepage
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
if ($menu->getActive() == $menu->getDefault()) {
    //This line makes it hide the class
    $('.search-wrapper').css('display','none');
}
```

Comment: You have mixed php and jquery, and not all Joomla sites are using jquery.  This will not work.

Comment: @Richard B thank you, indeed i was mixed up with joomla and normal websites because i always use jquery :)

Comment: Furthermore to use Javascript to do such basic CSS stuff seems overly complicated and a bad division of content, layout and styling.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method - Create a custom HTML module that you publish only to the homepage.
Extensions -> Module Manager -> New -> Custom HTML

Within that module, switch to code view instead of the wysiwyg editor, and create a style 'block'. All you need to do is use a more specific CSS rule to overrule the css in your stylesheets.

Assuming your stylesheets currently reference only the one class - then pre-pending the selectors with the id of one element from any parent container will be more 'specific'.

```
<style type="text/css">
#some-id .search-wrapper {display:none;}
</style>
```

Obviously replace 'some-id' with the actual id of a parent/grand-parent/etc element.